# wordpress template page.php being used over custom.php

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I am creating a website and theme on wordpress. I cannot share the website with you as it is password protected by the client.

There is a career page with the slug *career* and it successfully uses the custom template career.php over page.php.

However, the contact page with the slug *contact* uses page.php over contact.php

My about page used to work fine, using about.php as its template but now it also using page.php instead.

Any ideas why?

Comment: See if you can reproduce the problem in another environment or something; we have almost NOTHING to go off of, except start guessing based on previous experiences, which is not suitable as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your page (that you want the "contact" to be using) to `page-contact.php`

**Addition based on question in comment**

You are not using "defined" page template, so it will not show up like that in body element, but there is anothe way. You can put following code in your functions.php file which will add 'page-contact' as additional class in body classes, which you can use in your css (instead of 'page-template-contact').

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_slug_body_class' );
function add_slug_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    $classes[] = $post->post_name;
    return $classes;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my stylesheet I had specific styles for the contact page such that a body with the class page-template-contact was styled. Now the specific class on the body is page-id-683. Is there a way to change that class to page-contact perhaps?

Comment: @DB1500: I have updated my answer to cater what you have asked in comment. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the basic documentation:

> Page templates are a specific type of template file that can be
>   applied to a specific page or groups of pages.
>
> Since a page template is a specific type of template file, here are
>   some distinguishing features of page templates:
>
> Page templates only apply to pages, not to any other content type
>   (like posts and custom post types). Page templates are used to change
>   the look and feel of a page. A page template can be applied to a
>   single page, a page section, or a class of pages. Page templates
>   generally have a high level of specificity, targeting an individual
>   page or group of pages. For example, a page template named
>   page-about.php is more specific than the template files page.php or
>   index.php as it will only affect a page with the slug of “about.” If a
>   page template has a template name, WordPress users editing the page
>   have control over what template will be used to render the page.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Good Luck